# Make two Objets to mach

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster

So I have two objects one comes from my DTO and the other From the User service.

I want to blind a previously saved value to the select.

but because the objects are different is not showing the value (thats what i think)

This is the object with the data.

[image]

And this is the objets from the list in the select

[image]

¿So how I can delete or filter it to mach?

Comment: Can you rely on the Id? compare them by Id..

Comment: @Aragorn yes but in that case I had to set the [ngValue]="userOption.id" an then when I try to make the update the DTO requires a User object no a Long

Comment: ngValue doesn't have to be userOption.id, post your code, someone will be able to suggest an improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was doing wrong JHipster generate in the DTO a Long usuarioId then in the Angular side they get all the Users and compare the id when I save the entity I get the User objete using the UserService find by login.

So this is the way it works I think maybe some can find helpful

first in the ManyToMany relationship

```
 @ManyToOne
 @JsonIgnoreProperties("")
 private User coordinador;
         public User getCoordinador() {
            return coordinador;
        }

        public ExtendedUser coordinador(User user) {
            this.coordinador = user;
            return this;
        }

        public void setCoordinador(User user) {
            this.coordinador = user;
        }
```

And in the DTO

```
  private Long coordinadorId;

  private String coordinadorLogin;

  public Long getCoordinadorId() {
        return coordinadorId;
    }

    public void setCoordinadorId(Long userId) {
        this.coordinadorId = userId;
    }

    public String getCoordinadorLogin() {
        return coordinadorLogin;
    }

    public void setCoordinadorLogin(String userLogin) {
        this.coordinadorLogin = userLogin;
    }
```

In the angular side this is how it look the component.html

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="sigemApp.extendedUser.coordinador" for="field_coordinador">Coordinador</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="field_coordinador" name="coordinador" [(ngModel)]="extendedUser.coordinadorLogin" >
                        <option [ngValue]="null"></option>
                        <option [ngValue]="userOption.login" *ngFor="let userOption of users; trackBy: trackUserById">{{userOption.login}}</option>
    </select></div>
```

Finally in the component.ts

```
users: IUser[];
 this.userService.query().subscribe(
            (res: HttpResponse<IUser[]>) => {
                this.users = res.body;
            },
            (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
        );
 trackUserById(index: number, item: IUser) {
        return item.login;
    }
getSelected(selectedVals: Array<any>, option: any) {
        if (selectedVals) {
            for (let i = 0; i < selectedVals.length; i++) {
                if (option.id === selectedVals[i].id) {
                    return selectedVals[i];
                }
            }
        }
        return option;
    }
```

To save it i use the userService to get the User user object so in the User service

```
    Optional<User> coordinador = userRepository.findOneByLogin(extendedUserDTO.getCoordinadorLogin());
  updateExtendedUser.setCoordinador(coordinador.get());
        extendedUserService.save(updateExtendedUser);
```